# Docker workflow for automated builds on Github-Dockerhub

Tags: git, github, docker, workflow, dockerhub

I already have set up a github repository with 3 branches (master, dev and docker). I already set up successfully and linked the automated build on dockerhub. Each time a push is done on Github an image is built on Dockerhub with different tag (latest for master, beta for dev and alpha for docker). This is working fine. Now the problem...

On Dockerfile, there is a `git clone` command to retrieve the project. The problem is this is pointing to master always. So if I push something to docker branch for example (it builds image with alpha tag) the code of project on that image is the code of master and not code of branch docker which is the desired for this case.

If I modify the Dockerfile of branch docker (which generate alpha tagged image) and I put `git clone -b docker ...` the build is ok, but after all the tests, when I want to merge with a pull request from docker branch to dev branch for example, another updated is needed on dev to change the `git clone` command inside of Dockerfile to point to the right branch. And the same with a pull request from dev to master with the additional difficult of on this project the master branch is protected and I can't push directly to master... so after a pull request from dev to master I can't fix Dockerfile changing the Dockerfile to change `git clone` to point again to master.

Is there a way to have different branches with different tags on automated building without changing anything after pull requests from one to other branch? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using automated builds, this is what happens;

- Docker Hub (or Docker Cloud, which has some more advanced features) checks out the git commit that triggered the build
- It builds the Dockerfile that you configured to build from in your automated build

From the above; you should *not* `git clone` inside your Dockerfile *at all*, because you'd be doing what's already done by the automated build. Simply do;

```
FROM some-base-image

# Copy your project's source into the image
COPY . /my-src
RUN do-something-with-the-source
```

Docker Cloud has advanced features, which allow you to run custom scripts at various stages of the automated build, using [build phase hooks (documentation)](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/advanced/#custom-build-phase-hooks). This allows you (for example) to make "minimal" images by building your project in a "build image", then copying the generated code to a local directory, and building the final image from that.

**edit**

The Automatic build options on Docker Cloud has more features than Automatic Build on Docker Hub. For example, the Dockerfile to build, and the build-context can be set separately. This allows you to have a Dockerfile in a subdirectory, but use files outside of that subdirectory to be used as the build context. To do this, set the Dockerfile location to (e.g.) `/docker/Dockerfile`, and the buildcontext to `/`

[image]

Comment: It didn't worked. I removed the `git clone`from Dockerfile and tried `COPY . /some/existing/path/inside/the/container` and after a push, the automatic build failed in a command after this because the files are not there. I mean, the COPY command is not copying my project into the container. I tried also `COPY .. /some/existing/path/inside/the/container` because my Dockerfile is inside a /docker dir on the project... but it didn't worked either. Any other idea?

Comment: my project have dockerfile inside a /docker directory... and with `COPY . /some/existing/path/inside/the/container` is copying only content of /docker folder which have only Dockerfile and a README.md. I need to copy the parent directory and all of its directories (doesn't care if /docker is copied or not). How to achieve this? As I said in other comment. Using `COPY .. /some/existing/path/inside/the/container` generated this error `Build failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: .. ()`

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis I added some extra information and a screenshot

Comment: Thx for the help. Dockercloud seems more "professional" than Dockerhub. It seems the automated build is free only while in beta, so maybe it can work for now. I see I can login with my Dockerhub account (same user/pass) but what happens if I set up here an automatic build too with the right context settings. Which have preference? I mean, after a push, image is going to be pushed to dockerhub and dockercloud I guess. And if a user do a docker pull, from where is he going to download the image? from Dockerhub or Dockercloud? should I remove Dockerhub repository or at least automated build?

Comment: I tested a little bit. It seems it first builds on Dockerhub and then on Dockercloud. If you pull while still building on Dockercloud it's downloaded the Dockerhub's image. After finish building on Dockercloud, it's downloaded from Dockercloud, so it seems Dockercloud has preference. Maybe is better to remove Dockerhub's repository. Will see if once removed you still appear on searches. And now another problem... you know readme is automatically set once built, I prepared a special readme on same dir as Dockerfile and now on Dockercloud is taking main readme instead of this because of context.

Comment: The reason of having a special Readme for Dockerhub/Dockercloud is because my main Readme have a lot of mix of markdown and html. On the other hand, Dockerhub/Dockercloud Readme is only using pure markdown, html is not working there. And as I said in my last comment, now with all the stuff of the context the image is building ok but the Readme uploaded is the main Readme which is seen broken on Dockercloud. Oh man, this is a headache... :/

Comment: Ok, the final solution is a little tricky, but there is no other choice. I think I'll keep the repository on Dockerhub without automatic build and I'll put on its readme refs and links to the project and to Dockercloud explaining it was migrated to Dockercloud. In this way I'll keep appearing on searches on Dockerhub. Regarding the readme "problem". I'll open wiki for all documentation using markdown and html, and I'll keep only one main Readme with pure markdown.I think is the only way to go to reach all goals.I marked your answer as solution.Anyway if you have other idea, is welcome. :)

Comment: Yes, the README parsing is not really ideal on Docker Hub / Docker Cloud, this is a known issue, and I think being worked on. w.r.t. "where" the image ends up; both Docker Cloud and Docker Hub publish the images to the same place, so that does not make a difference. Once you set auto-build on Docker Cloud, you could remove it from Docker Hub

Comment: As a workaround, you can consider having a separate "documentation" directory on GitHub (or GitHub pages), that you link to from the README